# command failed when invoked as npm task, but work fine if start from cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, permissions, npm

I'm writing unit-tests and run them with ['jasmine-es6'](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-es6) 
and when I run them with simple `jasmine` command from cmd on my `Windows 10` it's work fine.

However I made a super simple task for npm which looks like `"test":"jasmine"` but when I run `npm test` it's fails with following error:

```
C:\_projects\git\miestby>npm test

> miestby@0.0.1 test C:\_projects\git\miestby
> jasmine

C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\transformation\file\logger.js:45
    throw new Constructor(this._buildMessage(msg));
    ^

ReferenceError: [BABEL] C:\_projects\git\miestby\test\app\common\list-pager.spec.js: Unknown option: presets
    at Logger.error (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\transformation\file\logger.js:45:11)
    at File.normaliseOptions (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\transformation\file\index.js:17
4:29)
    at new File (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\transformation\file\index.js:152:10)
    at Pipeline.transform (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\transformation\pipeline.js:127:16)

    at Object.transformFileSync (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\api\node.js:118:37)
    at compile (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\api\register\node.js:115:20)
    at normalLoader (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\babel-core\lib\babel\api\register\node.js:166:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\babel-core\lib\bab
el\api\register\node.js:179:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\jasmine-es6\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:71:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Jasmine.loadSpecs (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\jasmine-es6\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:70:18)
    at Jasmine.execute (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\jasmine-es6\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:154:8)
    at runJasmine (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\jasmine-es6\node_modules\jasmine\lib\command.js:102:11)
    at Command.run (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\jasmine-es6\node_modules\jasmine\lib\command.js:49:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\jasmine-es6\node_modules\jasmine\bin\jasmine.js:11:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:425:26)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:432:10)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\babel-core\lib\bab
el\api\register\node.js:177:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at C:\_projects\git\miestby\node_modules\jasmine-es6\bin\jasmine.js:20:3
    at FSReqWrap.cb [as oncomplete] (fs.js:216:19)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

How to fix this error? One of my guess is that problem could be releated to `npm` permissions.

Comment: Your cmd comand uses the global Installation your test script the local maby they are different?